# The result is not displayed when I run the program

Tags: python, python-3.x

The result of my python program is not displayed when I run it.

[Here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJFi.png)

Comment: Hi user15216987, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not include screenshots of code in your question, include it as actual text. Please read the [tour] and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `displayResults(factor)` at line 10.
Line 37 you wrote `print (output)` instead of `print(output)`
Line 16 same mistake.

In term of style there are too much comments.  At line 36 also you
forgot to use spaces around the equal symbol.

line 27
replace with
`while i <= n:`

line 31 replace `i=i+1` by `i += 1`
replace line 32 by
`if factor not in (1, 0, n):`
Line 32 is wrong since a parenthesis is stuck to the `if`

You are not experienced enough to make modules so don't check if **name** is
equal to main in order to call the main function.  Python is not C.  You don't
need to have parenthesis around your conditions.
line 1, 2
use `"""` delimiter for your comments on multiple line.  If possible move
the comment in the function main() as python help will display your comment.

---

There are probably many other mistakes.  I would suggest you to :

- Read some kind of python programmers manual or reference http://web.mit.edu/18.417/doc/pydocs/ref.pdf
- Not to watch crappy tutorials on the internet, ALWAYS read the official documentation on python.org.
- Make your programs as simple and readable before optimizing them.
- When you write spaghetti code (i.e. unreadable code) rewrite it
- Avoid using IDEs while learning.  Doing so will force you not to repeat your
  mistakes.
- When something doesn't work, read closely the error logs before coming
  to any forums or even performing a google search.  This will learn you to
  fix mistakes by yourself and learn.

Comment: The `print (output)` will actually work OK, it's more of a style thing. I do agree with your points

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! It's my second week of learning how to code, will try to use your tips.

Comment: No problem.  We have all been beginners.

Comment: Also, stackoverflow uses the markdown syntax. You can write **bold** using two asterixes (maybe also with two `_`). Write your code between grave accents (tree grave accents if multiple line). example 
```
MY CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call

```
displayResults(factor)
```

in your main() program after you calculated the factor